# Mount Vue 3 Instance on an on the fly created DIV

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to mount a vue instance on a div that I'm creating on the fly on the main.js file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "@/assets/styles/index.scss";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";
const app = createApp(App).use(store);
let div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.setAttribute("id", "widget");
app.mount("#widget");
```

When I do this I'm getting this error

> value cannot be made reactive: null

I'm assuming this is because I'm not waiting for the DOM element to actually load in the DOM in order to mount the Vue instance but I can't find an approach to do this correctly. Something like this is also not working for me :

```
setup() {
  onMounted(() => {
    if(document.getElementById("new-div")) {
      const app = createApp({});
      app.mount('#new-div');
    }
  });
}
```

I was just wondering if I have to mount the app somewhere else (maybe in the App component or in my wrapper comoponent on the onMounted hook).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by moving the code that creates the div element and mount the Vue app inside a DOMContentLoaded event listener like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.setAttribute("id", "widget");
  app.mount("#widget");
});
```

Alternatively, you can move the div element that you want to mount the Vue app on it to the HTML file instead of creating it in JavaScript.

```
    <div id="widget"></div>

    app.mount("#widget");
```

Comment: this don't resolve the problem. I still get the warning.